# Printing character in a string c

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to print the longest word in string but the loop is not running, I couldn't find a solution for this one.

```
    char str[50];
    int i = 0, count = 0, numOfWords = 0, place;

    printf("Please enter a sentence: ");
    gets(str);

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] != ' ') {
            numOfWords++;
            if (str[i + 1] == ' ') {
                if (numOfWords > count) {
                    count = numOfWords;
                    place = i + 1 - numOfWords;
                    numOfWords = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    puts(str);
    printf("%d", count);
    printf("The word is:\n");
    for (i = place; i < numOfWords; i++)
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    getch();
```

Comment: Note: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: @MikeCAT I was thinking the same. `gets()` is dangerous.

Comment: Run it under a debugger, step through...

Comment: gets() is fine for a prototype or proof of concept. Nothing scary about it.

Comment: This is what i was taught to do, i don't want to write the sentence by myself in the program.

Comment: For debugging questions please always post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

- You should use `count` to determine how many times the last loop should be taken.
- You should also process the last word.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* This implementation is simple, but maximum readable length is decreased by 1 */
char* safer_gets(char* s, size_t max){
    char* lf;
    if (fgets(s, max, stdin) == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((lf = strchr(s, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0'; /* remove the newline character */
    return s;
}

int main(void){
    char str[51];
    int i = 0, count = 0, numOfWords = 0, place = 0;

    printf("Please enter a sentence: ");
    safer_gets(str, sizeof(str));

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            numOfWords++;
            if (str[i + 1] == ' ' || str[i + 1] == '\0')
            {
                if (numOfWords > count)
                {
                    count = numOfWords;
                    place = i +1- numOfWords;
                    numOfWords = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    puts(str);
    printf("%d", count);
    printf("The word is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%c", str[place + i]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```